# Laplace Transform to solve the initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using the Laplace Transform to solve the initial value problem:

$$y''+ y = \delta(t-2\pi), y(0) =0 ,y'(0)=1$$

Applying Laplace transformation we have $s(s+1)Y(s)=1+e^{-2\pi s}$. Thus $$Y(s) = \frac{1+e^{-2\pi s}}{s(s+1)} = \frac{1}{s(s+1)} + \frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{s(s+1)} $$

Let $F(s) = \frac{1}{s(s+1)} $. Then inverse laplace transform of $(s)$ is $1-e^{-t}$ and that of $\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{s(s+1)} $ is $$u(t-2\pi) (1-e^{-(t-2\pi)})$$

Thus the solution is $$y(t) = (1-e^t) +u(t-2\pi) (1-e^{-(t-2\pi)}) $$

---

Is the soution correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the LHS be $s^2 + 1$ and not $s(s+1$)?

Comment: @Moo ok...i got it

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+ y = \delta(t-2\pi),\quad y(0) =0 ,\quad y'(0)=1$$

Tanking Laplace transform both side,

$$\mathcal{L}\{y''\}+ \mathcal{L}\{y\} = \mathcal{L}\{\delta(t-2\pi)\} \qquad . .  . . . (1)$$
Now $$\mathcal{L}\{y\}=\bar{y}(p)$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{y'\}=p~\bar{y}(p)-y(0)=p~\bar{y}(p)$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{y''\}=p^2~\bar{y}(p)-p~y(0)-y'(0)=p^2~\bar{y}(p)-1$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{\delta(t-2\pi)\}=e^{-2\pi p}\qquad \text{as}\quad 2\pi \gt 0$$

From $(1)$,
$$p^2~\bar{y}(p)-1+\bar{y}(p)=e^{-2\pi p}\implies(p^2+1)\bar{y}(p)=e^{-2\pi p}+1$$
$$\bar{y}(p)=\frac{e^{-2\pi p}+1}{p^2+1}=\frac{e^{-2\pi p}}{p^2+1}+\frac{1}{p^2+1}$$
Therefore $$ y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\bar{y}(p)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{e^{-2\pi p}}{p^2+1}\}+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{p^2+1}\}=  \begin{cases}  2\sin t \quad \text{if} \ t\gt 2\pi\\ \sin t \quad \text{if} \ t \lt 2\pi\end{cases}$$

---

> - **(Second shifting property )** If $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(p)\}=f(t)$, then $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{e^{-ap}F(p)\}=g(t)$$where $g(t)= \begin{cases}  f(t-a) \quad \text{if} \ t\gt a\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \ t \lt a\end{cases}$
> - $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{a}{a^2+p^2}\}=\sin at$